# MATLAB complex number for arc length

Tags: matlab, calculus

I am not understanding why I am getting a complex number for arc length. It should come out to a real number. Can you please point me in the right direction?

```
v = @(t) (sqrt(((40.*8.*pi)./15).*(cos((8.*pi.*t)./15)).*(-sin((8.*pi.*t)./15)).^2 + (40.*pi./15).*(cos((4*pi.*t)./15)).^2 + (((3.*16).*(t.^2))./675).^2));

d = integral(v,0,15);
```

This is the answer I get: 90.4528 +10.4335i

Comment: May be because you have a negative sign inside a sqrt? Check your formula with say v(1).

Comment: Thank you but the negative gets squared so it is positive. I also tried getting rid of it all together and it did not fix it.

Comment: The `(cos((8.*pi.*t)./15))` term can be negative. You forgot the square?